# How can I add linked text in front of \ref{myRef}?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I am currently making references like this:

```
\section{BliBlaBlup} \label{sec:BliBlaBlup}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi pharetra
pharetra viverra. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et 
ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Suspendisse potenti. Curabitur mollis cursus 
libero, sed tempus ligula accumsan in. Nulla commodo metus quis nulla luctus 
quis euismod diam tincidunt.
[...]
As you can read in section~\ref{sec:BliBlaBlup} ...
```

Now, only the number that gets generated by `\ref{sec:BliBlaBlup}` is linked. But I would like to have `Section~\ref{sec:BliBlaBlup}` being linked. How can I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `\autoref`

Lowercase `section` is default for `\autoref`. But it can be changed:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand*{\chapterautorefname}{Chapter}
\renewcommand*{\sectionautorefname}{Section}
% ...
\begin{document}
...
As you can read in \autoref{sec:BliBlaBlup} ...
```

### `\hyperref[]`

Or manually:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
% ...
\begin{document}
...
As you can read in \hyperref[sec:BliBlaBlup]{Section~\ref*{sec:BliBlaBlup}} ...
```

The star form `\ref*{...}` avoids a nested link.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `\autoref` feature of `hyperref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{Blip}\label{blip}
What's this? A reference to \autoref{blip}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you want to capitalize the name and don't want to fiddle with `hyperref`'s settings, you can use `cleveref`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{Blip}\label{blip}
What's this? A reference to \Cref{blip}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "capitalize the name"? `\Cref` resulted in two `?` instead of a reference and `\autoref` did only link the number (so it gave me the same result as I get by now). Where does the text `section` come from? What if blip was a reference to a figure? How would I change the text in that case?

Comment: @moose You need to compile twice in order to solve the reference and get rid of the `??`. The `\autoref` issue probably depends on options you give to `hyperref`. If you want "Section 1" rather than "section 1" use `\Cref` with `cleveref`; with `\cref{blip}` you'd get "section 1". It works with any kind of standard references (sections, chapters, figures, tables, ...).